Almost no memory due to a failed installation
I unfortunately broke my system by installing a Mate distro. 22.04 LTS
Now I no longer have access to fix this.
Is there a tool I can use without logging into Linux?

I don’t really understand the problem or what you’re trying to do, sorry. Could you try to explain? If your system is broken, why not just reinstall afresh whatever OS you want?

Boot a live system on external media; and perform fixes from there, which doesn't require you to login to your installed system.  Your details are very vague though.  (Installation puts a system on disk, and doesn't change the state of RAM; if you had problems with the install itself, did you verify the ISO prior to write? and validate the write of ISO; as problems are regularly caused by those steps having issues & checks take seconds, diagnosis of problems caused by issues there take days.  You gave no clues as to what checks you've done)
